# Did Joseph travel through Judea to Get to Nazareth? (Matthew 2)

Tags: geography

Matthew 2:19-23

> <sup>**19**</sup> When Herod had died, behold, the angel of the Lord appeared in a dream to Joseph in Egypt <sup>**20**</sup> and said, “Rise, take the child and his mother and go to the land of Israel, for those who sought the child’s life are dead.” <sup>**21**</sup> He rose, took the child and his mother, and went to the land of Israel. <sup>**22**</sup> But when he heard that Archelaus was ruling over Judea in place of his father Herod, he was afraid to go back there. And because he had been warned in a dream, he departed for the region of Galilee. <sup>**23**</sup> He went and dwelt in a town called Nazareth...

[image: Map of Israel surrounding the city of Nazareth]

This question is basically about the route the family would have taken. I am presuming that they traveled from an Egyptian location with a large population of Jews (Alexandria being the prime candidate). If they traveled by land they would have gone through Judea to Nazareth. But if they traveled by sea they could have gone to a northern port such as Caesarea or Ptolemais (Acre). Both of these ports were used by Paul and his companions in Acts 21:7.

Is there anything in the Greek text or relevant histories/commentaries that sheds light on this? Did he go back to "Israel" (meaning Judea) first, perhaps intending to settle in Bethlehem, and then hear about Archelaus?  Or did he hear about Archelaus during his journey and decide to go north, being "warned in a dream," thus skipping Judea? Could he have taken a ship to a Judean port such as Jaffa and then immediately gone on to a northern port to avoid Archelaus?

Answer (score 1):

**The Highway to Nazareth** Having studied and taught Biblical Geography, it became informative to see that there were several
*highways* that went from Egypt north to Israel and points beyond. One of the major routes was called **the Way of the Sea** (*Via Maris*) and it followed the coast of the Mediterranean Sea. (Actually, there were two parallel routes here.) This is referred to in Acts 8:26 when Philip ministered to the Ethiopian.

There was a minor road that went from Egypt through the Sinai through Hebron, and to Jerusalem, but this was not as important a road.

The major route that Joseph and Mary would have taken was called **the Way of the Kings** or "the Kings' Highway." It went through the Sinai Peninsula up through Edom, along the east side of the Dead Sea, and on upward to Syria and over to Babylon.  This is similar to the path that Moses and the ancient Israelites took on their way to the Promised Land.

After traveling along the East side of the Jordan River they would come to the east/west road that traversed the Valley of Jezreel. This went by the village of Nazareth, which was their destination! This was not a very isolated town, since there was also a road from Sepphoris, just a few miles northwest, to the spas on the southern side of the Sea of Galilee where Herod Antipas had another palace...and then going on up to Capernaum, and parts north caravans and merchants shipped their wares. So little Jesus was exposed to many types of people while growing up.

This path of the Holy Family, along the Kings' Highway, bypassed the region of the treacherous Archaelaus (Judea) and safely brought them home.

**Historical Note** Orthodox rabbis considered themselves "contaminated" if they traveled through Samaria on their way from Judea to Galilee, so they also took the same route the Holy Family took along the east side of the Jordon River, even though it was a longer trip. Jesus spent much of His ministry "Beyond Jordon" (also called Perea) to avoid persecution in Judea (Matthew 19:1, John 10:39-40). Still, not bound by tradition, at times Jesus deliberately traveled through Samaria to preach and heal (Luke 17:11). He did not share the same prejudices against the Samaritans as did the rabbis of Jerusalem. He even used the "Good Samaritan" as a parable.

**Map Accuracy** The Map pictured in this posted Question is inaccurate and misleading! The territory south of Galilee was **not** Judea, but Samaria. To the south of Samaria was Judea, and farther south was Idumaea. This map tends to skew the answers and comments.

All these territory locations militate against the Holy Family taking the *western route* to Nazareth. Idumaea was the birthplace of the wicked King Herod...Judaea was the present territory of mean Archaelaus, whom the Holy Family was trying to avoid...and Samaria would not be friendly to a Jewish family if they knew they were heading toward Galilee.

Also with that, if the Family took the western route they would be passing by several Egyptian forts along the way out of Egypt. These would be intimidating.

Just as Moes was led out of Egypt, and went along the King's Highway, it was typologically fitting that *He who is born King of the Jews* would take the King's Highway out of Egypt, too.

> Out of Egypt I have led my Son. (Matthew 2:15)

Answer (score 0):

We are not told the exact rout taken by Jesus' parents in returning to the land of Israel.  However, we are aware of the following:

Following Herod the Great's death in 4 BC, his will decreed that his kingdom be divided between his three sons as follows:

- Herod Antipas ruled Galilee and Perea
- Philip ruled Iturea and Trachonitus
- Archelaus ruled Judea Samaria and Idumea

Archelaus was particularly violent - his tyranny and incompetence prompted the Jews to petition Rome to have him replaced.  This was granted in 6 AD when he was replaced with a Roman Procurator.

The exact boarder between Judea and Galilee is uncertain and probably moved a little from time to time and depended on who one asked.  However, assuming (as would be most probable) that Joseph returned from Egypt via the coast road, he might have been intending to settle in Bethlehem, his ancient family town, as is suggested by the aorist tense of Matt 2:21 -

> And having arisen, he took the Child and His mother and came into the
> land of Israel.

Thus, it appears that Joseph and family did travel to "Israel".  But, following the third dream from the angel in Matt 2:22, he decided to travel further north to the region of Galilee and settled in Nazareth.

Meyer sums this well:

> Matthew 2:22. Augustus, after the death of Herod and the complications
> connected with it,[372] divided the kingdom amongst his three sons in
> such a manner that Archelaus received the half of the four quarters of
> the kingdom, namely, Judea, Idumaea, and Samaria; Antipas, Galilee and
> Perea; Philip, Batanea, Trachonitis, and Auranitis. Both the latter
> were called Tetrarchs, but Archelaus obtained the title of Ethnarch,
> Josephus, Antt. xvii. 8. 1, xvii. 11. 4, which was to be exchanged for
> the title of king should he prove worthy of it. But after nine years
> he was banished by Augustus on account of his cruelty to Vienne
> (Josephus, Antt. xvii. 13. 2; B. J. ii. 7. 3), and died there. His
> territory was added to the province of Syria, and placed under the
> administration of a procurator.

Comment: Any clues in the Greek as to the order of events, especially: did the dream-warning happen after arriving in Judea or en route? In the above translation, he "went to the land of Israel" which I suppose means Judea. Does that imply getting there, or only heading there when the dream came?  By the way, I lean toward an journey by sea rather than road... assuming they had funds left over from the Magi's gifts.

Comment: [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/68567/what-route-would-1st-century-bce-travellers-have-taken-from-alexandria-to-jerusa) discusses routes.

Comment: @DanFefferman - I have added a little to try and clarify the answer.  The coast road ("via Maris") is the most likely (= shortest) route as is suggested by the fact that they likely arrived in Judah.

Comment: @Dottard-If, as Meyer's quotation stated, Archelaus's territories included Idumaea, Judea, and Samaria---all being on the western route ---it would seem more probable that the Holy Family would take the eastern route to avoid Archelaus's tyranny. Peace.

Comment: @raygrant - you may be correct but we do not know.  My que is from the statement that Joseph appears to arrive in Judah and then decides to travel further north to avoid the territory ruled by Archelaus; but we are not given enough data to finally decide.

Comment: @Dottard-Not enough data, true! I'm not going to start a new denomination over this. But it is interesting to speculate, isn't it? This type of research underscores the humanity of the Holy Family, which had to make very real decisions (with the help of God)  in a very dangerous world.  Jesus took a drastic, traumatic move coming down here. The Incarnation was no joy ride, but we're so glad He did come.

Comment: @raygrant - I fully agree.